# How can I get an specific list item from ListView tap event in nativescript

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript

I'm trying to get data from a tap event using angular2 + typescript:

this is the component HTML:

```
<RadListView row="1" [items]="groceryList" [class.visible]="listLoaded" (tap)="seeItem($event)"
    swipeActions="true" (itemSwipeProgressStarted)="onSwipeCellStarted($event)">

    <ng-template let-item="item">
        <Label [text]="item.name" class="p-15 list-item"></Label>
    </ng-template>

    <GridLayout *tkListItemSwipeTemplate columns="*, auto">
        <StackLayout id="delete-view" col="1" (tap)="delete($event)" class="delete-view">
            <Image src="~/images/delete.png"></Image>
        </StackLayout>
    </GridLayout>
</RadListView>
```

This is the component code:

```
seeItem(args: ListViewEventData) {
    console.log('item ', <Grocery>args.object.bindingContext);
    console.log('in case');
}
```

When I tap an element from my ListView I get the console.log:

```
[Eric Guzmán’s iPhone]: item undefined
[Eric Guzmán’s iPhone]: in case
```

The "delete" event (in this component) works using the same logic, when tap:

```
delete(args: ListViewEventData) {
        let grocery = <Grocery>args.object.bindingContext;
        this.groceryService.delete(grocery.id)
            .subscribe(() => {
                let index = this.groceryList.indexOf(grocery);
                this.groceryList.splice(index, 1);
            });
    }
```

I'm a beginner in NativeScript and I would appreciate the help,

Comment: this won't work you are using RadListview and in grocery sample it is ListView. So grab the index `var index=args.itemIndex;` and then filter the array by that index i.e `this.groceryList[index];`

Comment: Thanks a lot, It worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you are expecting to get the item on tap, here are the changes you need to make

replace

```
<ng-template let-item="item">
        <Label [text]="item.name" class="p-15 list-item"></Label>
</ng-template>
```

with

```
<ng-template let-item="item">
        <Label [text]="item.name" (tap)="seeItem(item)" class="p-15 list-item"></Label>
</ng-template>
```

And make the changes in the function

```
seeItem(item: Grocery) {
    console.log('item ', item);
    console.log('in case');
}
```

Try this it should work.

Comment: This won't work as he wants to get the item when a swipe action is performed.